# Convergence in the discrete metric

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Let's suppose that $d$ is the discrete metric on $E$. How can I show that $(x_n)$ is convergent if and only if it is ultimately stationary? Meaning, if
and only if it has the form $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n, x, x, x, \dots)$ for some $n$.

Answer (score 1):

In the discrete metric $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\ne y$, $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$. Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$. Let's use the definition of limit with $\epsilon=1/2$. There exists $N$ such that if $n\ge N$ then $d(x_n,x)\le1/2$. That this tell you something about $x_n$ and $x$?